# How to get the world coordinates when clicking on an OpenGL window with c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, mfc, coordinates, coordinate-systems

this is the the [COpenGl Control](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) class, I have used so far in order to do my projects in MFC.
I have already written many navigation functions on this class like `pan`, `zoom tool`, `fixed zoom in`, `fixed zoom out` and etc and also I have managed to render an image on it.
And in all of those navigation tasks I have used mouse events and opengl window coordinates in order to implement.
Now in one part of the project ( which deals with registering a tiff image with the help of shapefiles` I need to use world coordinates:
For example, suppose that I zoom on the image and click a point, I need to know which pixel of the image I am zooming not the pixel of the opengl window.
Or suppose that, I zoom on the shapefile rendered in opengl and then click a point, I need to know what is the coordinates of the point that I have clicked for example (65696.5577,43995.3245) meters.

How can I achieve something like this in opengl?

- How can I get world coordinates of my rendered shape when I click on
  the opengl window no window coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches I have seen.

- If you're just interested in WHICH object you've clicked, some have done a render pass wherein every object is rendered an unique color and the pixel under the mouse is clicked.  Cannot recommend as this might not be reliable, and things like anti-aliasing break it.  Performance is not so hot if this is done every frame as the GPU driver has to wait until it is done drawing, stop to hand you the image back, then continue.
- If you have the transform matrix to hand, you can convert the mouse cursor location to normalized device coordinates (-1: left/bottom, 0: middle of screen, 1: right/top - though I may have got top/bottom mixed up there) and reverse the transform with a Z of -1 and 1, getting you the start and end of a ray you can perform collision with.  This is easy if you're using some unified mesh class or have a way to iterate all of the triangles in the scene.
- As a mixture of the two above methods, get the depth from the depth buffer, and (you'll need to linearize it) use it to interpolate between the near and far points on the ray.
- Iterate through every triangle in the scene, transforming them into normalized device coordinates and then screen space, (add one, multiply by screen width/height, divide by two) then do a point-in-triangle check against the triangles in screen space.  If you've retained the world space coordinates by the time you find the triangle being moused over, find the barycentric coordinates and multiply against the location of each vertex.